# Azure DevOps YAML Environment Auto-Deploy Trigger for New Servers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to use an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline to deploy to an AWS stack with EC2 instances and a Load Balancer. I've [read here](https://www.missioncloud.com/blog/aws-resources-integration-with-azure-devops-pipelines) that I can use the AWS userdata script to join new EC2 instances to the Azure DevOps Environment.

My question is, how can I get my Azure DevOps Environment or YAML build to deploy to new servers that join that group? For example, if I use auto-scaling and a new server spins up.

I know that Deployment Groups which are used in the Classic Pipelines had a feature that allowed you to enable a Post Deployment Trigger that could redeploy the last successful build when a new server joined [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#automatically-deploy-to-new-target-servers).

Is this possible to do with YAML Environments? If so, how?

If it matters, I hope to be able to share the AWS stack and have several separate applications that will get deployed to the same stack with their own YAML builds.